# Can Azure Table storage be used instead of Microsof SQL Server

Tags: web-applications, architecture, azure-table-storage

Planning for a fairly high scale web application and considering costs is it a good idea to use Microsoft Azure Table storage as primary database instead of Microsoft SQL Server?

I have already taken care of Authentication and Authorization using Identity, and CRUD operations on Table Storage. What might be the challenges or disadvantages in using Table storage instead SQL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that `Azure Table storage` is not a `relational data store` and does not provide the same relational data management functions as Azure SQL Database (such as joins and stored procedures). So this is the main challenge.

You can also refer to this doc [Table Storage vs. SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/jj553018(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#table-storage-vs-sql-database) for other disadvantages
/ advantages.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Yang. The relational features are not needed, functions of main programming language will work in place of procedures. So other than that nothing major I believe.

Comment: @ArvindSingh, another concern should be the performance related. You can follow these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query) to design a better performance table storage.

Comment: @ArvindSingh if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.